# Workaround NoClassDefFoundError for wrong directory structure

Tags: java, classloader

I am attempting to get a custom classloader to work with loading random `.class` files that could be anywhere on the filesystem. I wrote my class loader to extend `ClassLoader`, overrode the `findClass()` and `loadClass()` methods, and read in the byte stream of the class file. The issue arises when trying to invoke `ClassLoader.defineClass()`

The exact error I get is:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Test (wrong name: com/foo/bar/Test)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
```

I know that the problem is that the native classloading function doesn't like the fact that `Test.class` doesn't live in `/someDir/com/foo/bar/`. Is there any way I can make this work? My classloader already has code to check that the defined class conforms to a particular package. I really don't see why the native method would disallow this (other than security, which I don't need in this use case, and event then, let me shoot myself in the foot).

Comment: Are you in control of the class to load and hence can modify it? If so, is the package name needed? If not, simply don't define a package name then you should be able to load the class from any directory you want. The package name is actually a part of the class and hence requires certain byte manupulation frameworks like [Javassist](http://jboss-javassist.github.io/javassist/) to load the bytes and then update the "class" representation before actual loading via a classloader.

Comment: Later on I locate all loaded classes in a particular package, so I rely on the package name being something particular. However, id like to place that class file wherever I want in the directory structure and still load it.

Comment: Then have a look at Javassit (or an other byte-manipulation framework)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Native class loader, i.e. `ClassLoader.defineClass1`, does not know anything about directory structure. It just loads a byte array.

The error message says that the binary name passed as an argument to [`defineClass`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#defineClass-java.lang.String-byte:A-int-int-) does not match the actual name discovered from the class data bytes. The easiest workaround is to set `name=null` when calling [`defineClass`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#defineClass-java.lang.String-byte:A-int-int-).

**Note:** you cannot change a package of a class by simply moving it to a different directory. The package name is embedded in class file data. You have to either recompile sources with proper `package` directive or modify class files bytes with bytecode instrumentation framework while loading.

Comment: Wow, I can't believe it was that simple. That seems to have worked, thank you so much!